# why is there a 1MB payload limit in aws lambda + alb configuration?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-elb

AWS lambda can be used to create serverless applications, but it has some limits. One of these is a limit on the payload size: you can only return a maximum if 1MB payload from your function.

Does anyone know why this limit exists?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda limits the amount of compute and storage resources that you can use to run and store functions. AWS has deliberately put several Lambda limits that are either soft or hard to prevent misuse or abuse.

Here is the reference from AWS documentation [AWS Hard and Soft Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html)